# Should I hide optional views or add them at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

Suppose I have a `ViewGroup` that can contain several optional children views, say a `VideoView`, an `ImageView` and a few optional buttons.

Are significant resources wasted if I include all possible children views in the layout file but set all of them to visibility gone by default, but change visibility as appropriate at runtime?

Is it better just to add the views at runtime as needed?  Is there another approach that would be more sensible?  Fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to create them all and hide them. I've noticed that a most of the built-in Android layouts I've looked at do the same. Personally, I think it cuts down on NullPointerExceptions and the checks needed to avoid them.

Comment: Do you recall any specific built-in layouts you could cite for bonus points?  :)

Comment: alert_dialog_holo.xml, activity_list.xml, action_bar_home.xml, and action_bar_title_item to name a few. if you do a search for 'visibility="gone"' in the layout folder, you will get the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

The resources saved by not creating a handful of views in the layout file should normally not make a large difference for the runtime resource consumption of your application, except for cases where they contain huge images or other very heavy ressources.

On the other hand, having those views in the layout file (and hiding them)

- makes them much more readable than creating them in Java code
- leads to them being checked by Android Lint.

That's why I always suggest to have them in the layout.

Comment: The reasons for marking them gone in my case is that there will be no associated media (video, images, audio, etc.), so there won't be any resources attached to them.  Thanks for enumerating the benefits to static compile-time layout--I agree.